# How do I add the Boost library to my C++ program in XCode 6.0?

Tags: c++, xcode, boost

I'm using `XCode` 6.0 and need the `boost` library for program. I have downloaded `boost_1_57_0.tar.gz` from http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.57.0/ and have unarchized it. Now I just need to somehow get it into my program so that

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
using boost::filesystem;
```

works. I looked at the instructions http://freddy.cellcore.org/post/79587278354/boost-c-libraries-on-osx-xcode-5, which are for `XCode 5`, and I can't seem to find the equivalent "Build Phases" panel in XCode 6.

Upvotes to anyone who can offer me help.

Comment: "Build Phases" are **Target**- based. If you select your project file in the workspace explorer (the left-side panel) on the right side a split panel will be shown. The left side of that split panel will include the project (which you can further configure) as well as a **Targets** list. Select the target you're configuring and the "Build Phases" should be one of the top-tab options in the right side panel (the second one I believe). Dunno if that helps, but best of luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- here's a screenshot demonstrating how I do it:

then include boost headers like so:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

[image]

To get to the build settings, ensure your project view is open on the left, and then click on the actual target (the one highlighted in this picture)

[image]

If you can't even see that it's because you have to press this stupid, almost-invisible button here (third from right - looks like a vertical line inside a box):

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain how I get to Build Settings in the first place?

Comment: I mark the path as recursive and I get an error 'Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed'