# Difficulty linking Boost 1.60 on OS X after installing via Homebrew

Tags: c++, macos, boost, clang, homebrew

I have a fresh install of OS X 10.11.4 that I immediately installed the Xcode toolchain on, then Homebrew, then Boost 1.60. In order to test that everything had gone well, I wrote the following code on my Desktop.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::filesystem::path new_directory("hello");
    boost::filesystem::create_directory(new_directory);
}
```

I then attempted to compile it as I usually have done with the following command.

```
$ clang++ test.cpp -o test -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

I received the following error.

```
test.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'boost/filesystem.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

This is how I have always compiled projects that link Boost in the past. I'm assuming that I have probably forgotten a step along the way that allows clang to search a specific path to dynamically link the libraries. What should I change in order for this compilation command to work?

Comment: check that the system include paths in the xcode project include the path /usr/local/include

Comment: yup, I knew I'd answered this before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470462/how-do-i-add-the-boost-library-to-my-c-program-in-xcode-6-0

Comment: I'm not using Xcode (and I almost never do); I'm compiling a single file from Terminal. If I do this from within Xcode, will it change my settings for every clang compile permanently?

Comment: Ah, then you'll need to add the option -I<path/to/boost/installation>/include -L /path/to/boost/libs

Comment: But what should I do in order for -this- compilation command to work? I know it is possible, it is how I have always had it set up in the past. I've just forgotten how.

Comment: answer below. not sure where homebrew installs boost so you'll need to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

For me, boost has been compiled and installed into a subdirectory of my home directory, so you'll need to modify the paths as appropriate for your homebrew installation:

```
flags="-std=c++1z -I/${HOME}/local/include -L${HOME}/local/lib -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system"
c++ ${flags} -o jared jared.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the location of boost by doing the following:

`brew info boost`

[image]

From the image above, you can see that my location is

`/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.66.0`

Then, to compile, use the following:

`c++ -I /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.66.0 main.cpp -o boost`